# How to multiple dropdown options to add class to element when there are multiple dropdowns on the page?

Tags: jquery

I currently am running this code for a dropdown selection box. When different options are chosen, a class is added to a div element. So far all of this code works without an issue. The problem is I would like to have it work for multiple dropdown selectors on a single page. The div mcga_ has multiples of them which change "mcga_1, mcga_2, etc). I have tried running the code twice and changing the element names, but only one selector will work and the other will not do anything. Here is what works so far;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select[name*='custom_fields[mcgroup1]']").change(function(){
    select_changed();
    });
});

function select_changed(){
$("div[id*='mcga_']").each(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('addThis');
});
$("select[name*='custom_fields[mcgroup1]']").each(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('#'+selected).addClass('addThis');
});
}
```

That works without a problem. It adds the class "addThis" to every "mcga_*" div. I tried the following to make it work with a different dropdown as well on the same page, but to no avail.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select[name*='custom_fields[mcgroup1]']").change(function(){
    select_changed();
    });
});

function select_changed(){
$("div[id*='mcga_']").each(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('addThis');
});
$("select[name*='custom_fields[mcgroup2]']").each(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('#'+selected).addClass('addThis');
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select[name*='custom_fields[mcgroup2]']").change(function(){
    select_changed();
    });
});

function select_changed(){
$("div[id*='mcgb_']").each(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('addThis2');
});
$("select[name*='custom_fields[mcgroup2]']").each(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('#'+selected).addClass('addThis2');
});
}
```

Any help to get this code to clean up and work with multiple dropdown menu's will be great.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, Can you share the code of HTML CSS as well on some code snippets tool  like http://jsfiddle.net/. That will become more easier to understand this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you use the same function name for your change event. In a quick and dirty way you could call the function select_changed_2 or so.

For a cleaner way I would recommend data attributes for your select fields and work with them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select[name*='custom_fields']").change(function(){
    select_changed( $(this).attr('data-change-it') );
  });
});

function select_changed(change_IDs){
  $("div[id*='"+ change_IDs +"']").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('addThis');
  });
  $("select[data-change-it*='"+ change_IDs +"']").each(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('#'+selected).addClass('addThis');
  });
}
```

Your select field should get something like this:

```
<select name="custom_fields[mcgroup1]" data-change-it="mcga_"></select>
<select name="custom_fields[mcgroup2]" data-change-it="mcgb_"></select>
```

Comment: Hi. Due to the software I am using I am unable to add "data-change-it" to the selector. I am stuck with the name and class only. Having said that, changing the function name worked. It is now working on both dropdown menu's. Thanks very much! Is there a way to tidy the code using only what is available? (I can't add data attributes to the selector). Cheers.